# VueJS hello world example not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My VueJS code is not rendering data on the DOM. It makes Ajax requests, gets data properly, but won't render to the DOM.

To isolate, I tried the most basic of the DOM rendering example, and it still doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    {{ message }}
  </div>

  <script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

After putting that page on a webserver, and opening it in chrome, this is what I see in "view source":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its the same with Firefox. It works on JSFiddle, but not locally. What is going on here?

Comment: Did you `npm run dev` and go to the URL they give you (localhost:8000 or something)? or are you using a web server locally?

Comment: Its a django backend that is serving that html page.

Comment: `view source` always gives you the source before any javascript does anything on the page. Use the developer tools instead.

Comment: with the `runserver` command or what?

Comment: @ggdx yes, with `runserver`

Comment: It probably won't work if opened as a file in the browser. Make sure the page is opened using `http://` and not `file://`.

Comment: I don't see any issue here, vue.js is js script, not an engine so why should it render ur source code?

Comment: We need more info here

Comment: @ggdx What do you need me to give?

Comment: You probably need to escape vue tags `{{ message }}` because they are processed by Django, I don't know much about Django but there should be a way to pick different tags.

Comment: @jcubic oh jeez. Thanks! That's the problem. Django's template language is replacing those tags. Wow. This drove me insane.

Comment: That's weird. Why would django replace vue tags? You probably need to disable django's templating system since you ain't gonna need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by jcubic, the issue is that the file is being served by django, which is removing the tags `{{ message }}` while parsing the template.

Solution is to include `{% verbatim %}` tag where django shouldn't change anything.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea how django works. However, I suggest that you try to disable the templating system rather than escaping them

Comment: I still need to use Django's template system in some places.

Comment: I would personally argue against relying on two things(vue and django templates) which are intended for similar purposes. But can't have a strong opinion without seeing the actual requirement which may be perfectly valid. Cheers!!

Comment: Other option is to use different delimiters: `delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],`. Then instead of `{{ message }}` you would do `[[ message ]]`